# Need Combined SQL Query to Update 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having 2 tables. **Table1** and **Table2**. I need to update these 2 tables based on some conditions.

1. The SQL select query from Table1 will return multiple records, let's
   name it as **SQLQuery1**
2. From **SQLQuery1** results returned I need to loop through each record and
   execute another SQL query from **Table2** which will return only 1
   record,  let's name it as **SQLQuery2**
3. Update **Table1** and **Table2** with the results returned from **SQLQuery2**.

Is there is a single query to combine the above operations?

If you need more information please let me know

**UPDATE:**

Following are the Sample Queries used,

```
SELECT E.Id,E.Name 
from Employee E 
where E.transdate > '2019-01-201 00:00:01' -- Multiple Results(SQLQuery1)

SELECT top 1 ED.Id,ED.balance 
FROM EmployeeDetails ED  
where ED.Name= @Name  -- Single Results((SQLQuery2)

UPDATE Employee set IsProcessed=true 
where Id=@Id 

UPDATE EmployeeDetails set IsProcessed=true 
where Id=@Id
```

Comment: Please provide your query you already have.

Comment: You're trying to filter the results from Table1 on a condition and then locate a record from Table2 I guess. Are you flipping a boolean value or flag on the resulting record in both tables?  Or are you doing data validation to make sure both records are exactly the same in both tables?  Why would you need to update a row that you've just found to have the same values in Table2?

Comment: Please take a look at the SQl Queries i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an UPDATE with an INNER JOIN.  I have no idea if it's best practice at this point in time or whether there is a better way to do this but it works for the example I have created in dbfiddle.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE E
SET IsProcessed = 1
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN EmployeeDetails ED ON E.Id = ED.Id
WHERE E.transdate >= '2019-01-20 00:00:01' AND ED.name = 'Martin'

UPDATE ED
SET IsProcessed = 1
FROM EmployeeDetails ED
INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.Id = ED.Id
WHERE E.transdate >= '2019-01-20 00:00:01' AND ED.name = 'Martin'
```

I used **>=** because I just set all 3 created records to the datetime you have and forgot that looking for a datetime greater than that would provide me with nothing.  I also used a hard-coded name **Martin** instead of using a variable.

Here is my link to the dbfiddle I created in which I created Employee and EmployeeDetails, filled them with test data and then proceeded to identify the correct records using the date, time and name joined by their ID values:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4492b27a9790f34b0bff0996e7fb6d36

Comment: I would recommend using `UPDATE E`.  Defining a table alias -- and then not using it -- is really confusing.  I wish SQL Server generated an error in this case, as it would with similarly avoiding the alias in a `SELECT`.

Comment: Sounds good, let me update the dbfiddle I created and I'll edit this post afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INNER JOIN` :

```
update e
       set e.IsProcessed = 1 -- assuming BIT type
from employee e inner join
     EmployeeDetails ed
     on ed.name = e.name and ed.id = e.id
where e.transdate > '2019-01-201 00:00:01';

update ed
       set ed.IsProcessed = 1 -- assuming BIT type
from EmployeeDetails ed inner join
     Employee e
     on ed.name = e.name and ed.id = e.id and
where e.transdate > '2019-01-201 00:00:01';
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it like this.

You can use outer apply to get rid of the cursor:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_Query1
OUTER APPLY 
(
     SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_Query2
     WHERE T_Query2.query1_id = T_Query1.id
) AS tQuery2
```

Then you can do an update like this:

```
UPDATE A 
    SET some_value = tQuery2.some_new_value
FROM T_Query1 AS A 
OUTER APPLY 
(
     SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_Query2
     WHERE T_Query2.query1_id = A.id
) AS tQuery2
```

Besides that, you cannot update 2 tables with one update statement, AFAIK.

Your best bet would be

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT T_Query1.field1,  T_Query2.field2, T_Query2.newField1
    FROM T_Query1 
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
         SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_Query2
         WHERE T_Query2.query1_id = T_Query1.id
    ) AS tQuery2 
)
-- SELECT * FROM CTE 
UPDATE CTE SET field1 = newField1, field2 = newField1
```

but I don't think CTE updating can handle outer-apply.

Comment: It didn't worked for me. I have added sql queries used. can you please look at the Sample Queries used.